# How to log errors when Play Evolutions fail?

Tags: playframework-2.5, playframework-evolutions

I am just getting started with Play Evolutions and I find it pretty tough to figure out why they fail and leave the DB in an inconsistent state.

In Dev mode it will display the error in the default HTML page but it does not say which statement failed. This is also problematic since for this particular application I only have REST APIs that return JSON and so an HTML error is not appropriate. I have my own error handler so I will probably end up matching on `ExceptionAttachment` and pull out the content/script myself and escape that in the JSON error response. However this is only in DEV mode since I would not want this going back to a real user in PROD.

More frustrating is that it doesn't even log the statement when it fails. I can enable logging for my driver but once the failure has occurred it is too late to then go and enable logging.

Is there anyway to get a more specific error in the logs when an evolution fails?